# Exclude Columns in jsPDF AutoTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Has somebody experience excluding the columns in the pdf result from a Table using jsPDF autoTable..Would appriciate a little help.

Answer (score 8):

Anyway, after digging deep in the API and in the examples. I found a solution. jsPDF with autoTable is kinda tricky specially for beginners so for those who will bump in to this predicament in the near fututre. Here's how:

```
var tTB = document.getElementById("myTable");
var atTB = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(tTB, true);
var cols = atTB.columns;
//here you are going to set which column you will truncate. Moreover, .splice(index number of the column(your start), the number of columns you will exclude)
cols.splice(4,1); 
doc.text("My Test Table", 40, 60);
doc.autoPrint();
```

cheers!

Comment: I have been searching for a solution for quite some time - works perfectly

Comment: I don't know exactly how `doc.autoPrint` works, but if you want to invoke `doc.autoTable`, you need to pass it the columns as well as the rows. So you also need to loop through all rows and splice the column(s) you want to ignore, otherwise the data shown might not correspond to the correct column. You sent me in the right direction though.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use http://pdfmake.org/ to generate pdf client side. It is much simpler to write a pdf using this library. They also have playground to copy paste your code and watch live pdf.

Thanks,