# Exclude delete button when creating a pdf from HTML table

Tags: javascript

I want to print a HTML table into PDF. It is working fine but there is a delete button with every row in HTML table and I don't want to get that button printed. How can I exclude that delete button in the PDF?

```
<script>
function createPDF() {
  var sTable = document.getElementById('customer').innerHTML;

  var style = "<style>";
  style = style + "table {width: 100%;font: 17px Calibri;}";
  style = style + "table, th, td {border: solid 1px #DDD; border-collapse: collapse;";
  style = style + "padding: 2px 3px;text-align: center;}";
  style = style + "</style>";
  var win = window.open('', '', 'height=700,width=700');
  win.document.write('<html><head>');
  win.document.write('<title>localhost:5000</title>'); 
  win.document.write(style);          
  win.document.write('</head>');
  win.document.write('<body>');
  win.document.write(sTable);         
  win.document.write('</body></html>');
  win.document.close();     
  win.print();
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude Columns in jsPDF AutoTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254744/exclude-columns-in-jspdf-autotable)

Comment: You may be add css (display none to this button) i think it's working may be try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set some CSS in the HTML that you're creating to be printed which would hide the button when printing. For example:

```
function createPDF() {
  var sTable = document.getElementById('customer').innerHTML;

  var style = "<style>";
  style = style + ".myButtonClass {display: none !important;}";
  style = style + "table {width: 100%;font: 17px Calibri;}";
  style = style + "table, th, td {border: solid 1px #DDD; border-collapse: collapse;";
  style = style + "padding: 2px 3px;text-align: center;}";
  style = style + "</style>";
  var win = window.open('', '', 'height=700,width=700');
  win.document.write('<html><head>');
  win.document.write('<title>localhost:5000</title>'); 
  win.document.write(style);          
  win.document.write('</head>');
  win.document.write('<body>');
  win.document.write(sTable);         
  win.document.write('</body></html>');
  win.document.close();     
  win.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's simple string, you can replace unwanted part.

```
sTable.replace('<td>Delete Button</td>', '');
```

If your "delete button" is something dynamic, regular expressions may be handy.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, You want to hide the button in print view not on actual html page.

So here is what you'll need.

Add a `class` or `id` to the `td` containing delete button.
Add CSS media query for `print` as shown below:

```
@media print { 
          /* All your print styles go here */
     #deletBtn .delete-btn { display: none !important; } 
    }
```

This will hide the button whenever you are printing your HTML.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) is more on css media queries for print.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) is demo.